# How to disable a custom DataTables button in its action callback?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatables

This is in a C# ASP.NET MVC 5 web application, using DataTables version 1.10.22.

I configure a DataTable to have a custom button.  The action for the button is a callback function.  After that function executes once, I want to disable the button.

I can disable all buttons associated with the DataTable.  But, how do I disable just one button?

The DataTables documentation, such as https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons().disable(), has an example that seems to identify certain buttons by... their CSS class name?

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
var buttons = table.buttons( ['.edit', '.delete'] );
buttons.disable();
```

But, how do I uniquely identify my custom button?

The action callback function for the button seems to be provided with several parameters that represent the button.  But, the `node` does not seem to have a `disable()` function.  Changing `config.enabled` to false has no effect.  What else can I try?

The following is what I am trying to do in my Views/Foo/Index.cshtml:

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready( onReady );



  function onReady()
  {
    var config = {};

    config.buttons =
    [
      // A button to create data for the table.
      {
        text: '<span class="fa fa-plus"/>',
        titleAttr: 'Create states',
        action: createStates,
        enabled: true,
      }

      ... other buttons ...
    ];

    ... other configuration ...

    $( '#state-table' ).DataTable( config ) );
  }



  /**
   * Create the states.
   * 
   * Parameters:
   * e (object): The event.
   * table (object): The DataTable.
   * node (jQuery): The jQuery instance of the button that was clicked.
   * config (object): The button configuration.
   */
  function createStates( e, table, node, config )
  {
    //------------------------------
    // Create client-side state data in the table.
    table.clear();

    for ( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
      var data = { Id: i, Name: 'state ' + i };
      table.row.add( data );
    }

    //------------------------------
    // Calling draw() at the end updates the DataTable internal caches.
    table.rows().draw();

    //------------------------------
    // Disable the button, so that states cannot be created again.
    // *** How ? ***

    // Just changing this property has no effect on the button.
    config.enabled = false;

    // This disables all buttons, not just the one I want.
    table.buttons().disable();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each DataTables button can be given a button name and/or a class name - and then you can refer to that button using either of these - for example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    "buttons": [
      {
        text: 'My Button',
        className: 'myButtonClass',
        name: 'myButtonName'
      }
    ]
  } );

  table.buttons( '.myButtonClass' ).disable();
  //table.buttons( 'myButtonName:name' ).disable();

});
```

In the above example, the button has both a button name and a class name.

There are various additional ways to select one or more buttons:

```
buttons( selector );
```

These `selector` options are documented [here](https://datatables.net/reference/type/button-selector).

And, yes, that example in your question...

```
var buttons = table.buttons( ['.edit', '.delete'] );
```

...is indeed using the class name selector.

Comment: Thanks @andrewjames, that works perfectly.